# Creating a custom super user as part of a class Im taking

Tags: python, django

I'm currently taking a custom rest API class that is teaching me to build my own custom REST APIs for authentication, as well as creating custom user models.

Im running into a slight problem with the following code base:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

# Create your models here.

class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    """ Manager for User Profiles"""

    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        """ Create a new user profile"""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name)

        """  user.set_password(password) encrypts the passwords as a hash """
        user.set_password(password)

        """ This allows you to specify which database to use for the user accounts. Django Supports multiple Databases!!! 8D """
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superusr(self, email, name, password):
        """ Create and save a new superuser with given details """
        user = self.create_user(email, name, password)

        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """ Database model for users in system """
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        """ Retrieve Full Name of User"""
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        """ Retrieve short name of User"""
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        """Return String representation of our User """
        return self.email
```

The primary issue is in the UserProfileManager section, the issue according to the error output is with the create_superuser section.

The error message is the following:

AttributeError: 'UserProfileManager' object has no attribute 'create_superuser'

I've checked to ensure that in my settings.py file to ensure that using the custom model, as well as Ive checked to confirm that the makemigrations and migrations commands have been run. Ive also tested by deleting the **init** files, as well as the database and rebuilding them.

Ive also tested to ensure that superuser works, and django admin portal is enabled, all of which without the custom user profile works fine, but with it it breaks, so I know my issue should have something to do with the section of code above, but I cant find anything. Ive checked with the official django docs, but Im at a loss at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I found my error. E for Error, as in the e that was missing in def create_superusEr.

Im good now! This site is awesome! Sometimes just asking the question helps to answer it.